# iOS Phonegap regex replace

Tags: iphone, ios, regex, cordova, replace

I might just be doing something obvious and dumb here, but I can get this code to work in the Chrome console, but when I run it in my phonegap app it just doesn't do anything.

I'm pulling in some messages from an website API to a phonegap companion app. The problem is the messages have links in them to the website. I want to use regex to change the href to an onClick so it works with my app.

If I run this code in Chrome it's fine:

```
avar = '<a href="view.php?id=63">Click here to view details</a>';
bvar = avar.replace(
    /<a href="view\.php\?id=([0-9])*">/gi,
    '<a onClick="navigator.notification.alert(\'ok\')">AAA'
);
```

I stripped the regex right back to this, and it still fails

```
bvar = avar.replace(
    /<a href="/gi,
    'TEST'
);
```

Again that works in Chrome and not the Phonegap app. Any ideas?

Comment: are you getting any js errors in the logs?

also, what phone is it running on? android? ios?

Comment: I don't know how to log js errors into xcode. It's just acting like the regex isn't matching as it continues on fine. And it's iOS (as it states in the title)

Comment: you can log to the xcode debug window with console.log('something') - and keep an eye on the debug window in xcode when that regex code runs, in case it outputs a js error

Comment: Ok, the debug window doesn't show anything when it runs. It's acting like it just doesn't match the regex as soon as the double quote - " is present. It works for <a href=, but fails on <a href=".

Answer (score 0):

if it seems to have issues with the ", try putting brackets around what you are regex-ing:

```
bvar = avar.replace(
    /(<a href=")/gi,
    'TEST'
);
```

also, using the console.log, just check that the regex is getting registered in js correctly.

```
var rgxtest = /(<a href=")/gi
console.log(rgxtest);
```