# Does phonegap support regex

Tags: cordova

every body.

Could you tell me whether phonegap support regex? I tried to use regex on iOS Phonegap project, but it didn't run.

For example, I use regex to check if a hyperlink, and it not work

```
var pattn = '^http[s]?\:\/\/[^\/]*';
var url = 'http://google.com';
var regx = new RegExp(pattn, 'gi');

if (url.match(regx)) {
  console.log('Match');
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does. [Sometimes it can be odd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545535/ios-phonegap-regex-replace). Try simplifying your pattern and isolating where it fails.  `var pattn = '^https?:\/\/';`

Answer (score 1):

After diving into Phonegap, I found that Phonegap support regex, but it has a bit different:

```
var pattn = '^http[s]?\:\/\/[^\/]*';
var url = 'http://google.com';
var regx = new RegExp(pattn, 'gi');

if (regx.test(url)) {
  console.log('Match');
}

regx.exec(url);
```